# Re-prompt user to input a valid input in java

Tags: java

I have a code that requests input from the user, it runs just fine however I want to re-prompt the user to input a valid response instead of continuing to run.

Here's the code:

```
import java.io.*;
public class SkiLodge {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {

        InputStreamReader ui = new InputStreamReader (System.in);
        BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(ui);

        System.out.println("Select Membership Type: (Gold/Silver/Bronze)");
        String membership = inputReader.readLine();

        double x = 0d;

        if (membership.equals("Gold"))
            System.out.println("Gold Membership Selected: £" + (x = 750));
        else if (membership.equals("Silver"))
            System.out.println("Silver Membership Selected: £" + (x = 450));
        else if (membership.equals("Bronze"))
            System.out.println("Bronze Membership Selected: £" + (x = 250));
        else System.out.println("Invalid Membership");



        System.out.println("Do you require snow tyre rental? (yes/no)");
        String tyreRental = inputReader.readLine();


        if (tyreRental.equals("yes"))
            System.out.println("The total so far with tyre rental: £" + (x = x * 1.1));
        else if (tyreRental.equals("no"))
            System.out.println("The total so far without tyre rental: £" + x);
        else System.out.println("Invalid response");

        System.out.println("Would you like to reserve parking? (yes/no)");
        String parking = inputReader.readLine();

        if (parking.equals("yes"))
        System.out.println("Membership total: £" + (x = x * 1.08));
        else if (parking.equals("no"))
        System.out.println("Membership total: £" + x);
        else System.out.println("Invalid response");
    }

}
```

So for example if the user inputs Gold, the program prints out 750, if not then it prints out invalid membership and asks for a valid one.

Same goes for the following questions, so the program only accepts yes and no as valid responses.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a do-while loop.

```
do{
    //Some code here

    //if block
    else { // last else block.
         System.out.println("Invalid Membership");
         continue;  // This will skip the rest of the code and move again to the beginning of the while loop.
    }

    //More code

    break; // If the condition was correct, then you need not worry. This statement will pull out of the loop.
}while(true);
```

You can modify this to put a do-while loop any where you have such requirement.

This would make your whole code to:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{

    InputStreamReader ui = new InputStreamReader (System.in);
    BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(ui);
    String membership, tyreRental,parking;
    double x = 0d;
    do
    {
        System.out.println("Select Membership Type: (Gold/Silver/Bronze)");
        membership = inputReader.readLine();

        if (membership.equals("Gold"))
            System.out.println("Gold Membership Selected: £" + (x = 750));
        else if (membership.equals("Silver"))
            System.out.println("Silver Membership Selected: £" + (x = 450));
        else if (membership.equals("Bronze"))
            System.out.println("Bronze Membership Selected: £" + (x = 250));
        else{
            System.out.println("Invalid Membership");
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }while(true);

    do{
        System.out.println("Do you require snow tyre rental? (yes/no)");
        tyreRental = inputReader.readLine();

        if (tyreRental.equals("yes"))
            System.out.println("The total so far with tyre rental: £" + (x = x * 1.1));
        else if (tyreRental.equals("no"))
            System.out.println("The total so far without tyre rental: £" + x);
        else{ System.out.println("Invalid response"); continue;}
        break;
    }while(true);

    do{
        System.out.println("Would you like to reserve parking? (yes/no)");
        parking = inputReader.readLine();

        if (parking.equals("yes"))
            System.out.println("Membership total: £" + (x = x * 1.08));
        else if (parking.equals("no"))
            System.out.println("Membership total: £" + x);
        else {System.out.println("Invalid response"); continue;}
        break;
    }while(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no really elegant way of avoiding two input statements in this situation. There are various ways of doing this but I find the neatest is the most straightforward:

```
System.out.println("Select Membership Type: (Gold/Silver/Bronze)");
String membership = inputReader.readLine();
while (!membership.matches("Gold|Silver|Bronze")) {
    System.out.println("Illegal membership Type; please enter one of Gold, Silver or Bronze");
    membership = inputReader.readLine();
}
```

Ideally you would encapsulate some of that logic so that you weren't repeating it in several places. That will make your code a bit neater. For example:

```
enum Membership {
    GOLD(750),
    SILVER(450),
    BRONZE(250);

    private int value;

    Membership(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public static Membership getByName(String name) {
        for (Membership membership: values())
            if (name.toUpperCase().equals(membership.name))
                return membership;
        return null;
    }
}

System.out.println("Select membership type: " + Membership.values());
Membership membership = Membership.getByName(inputReader.readLine());
while (membership == null) {
    System.out.println("Illegal membership Type; enter one of " + Membership.values());
    membership = Membership.getByName(inputReader.readLine());
}
int x = membership.getValue();
```